# Change event's calendar when invited to event

Tags: google-calendar

I have been invited to an event by a colleague. The event, by default, was added to my first calendar: the one that existed when I created the Google Calendar account. I would like to switch that to another calendar. I can do it if I duplicate the event, but I don't want to have two instances of the same event on my calendar.

For instance, my default calendar is "Personal Events". Another calendar is "Professional Events". Since this event is work-related, I want to move it from Personal to Professional but I can't do that without duplicating.

When I am not the owner of an event, how do I change the calendar an event belongs to without duplicating the event?

Comment: I have a [similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/138166/140429), hoping this has been fixed somehow. It makes no sense to me that as an invitee to an event, I can't categorize it.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, since it's not originating from your calendar, you can't change it from your default calendar. All you can do is "copy" to the other calendar (and, possibly, delete the original).