# How do I change the calendar of an existing Google Calendar event?

Tags: google-calendar

I'm seemingly able to change the calendar for an existing Google Calendar for an event that I have created; and no way to do it on any client for events to which I have been invited. Moreover when I attempt to change the calendar for an event I have created I get unexpected behavior. If I attempt to change in Apple's macOS Mail client, for example, I get the warning

> **Are you sure you want to move this event from the account “Google” to the account “Google”?**
>   If you move an event between accounts, the original event will be canceled, a new event will be created, and new invitations will be sent to your invitees. However, some invitees may not be available in the new account.

which suggests that moving an event between calendars is the same as moving them between *accounts*. While if I "change" the calendar in the Google Web interface for the account from which I invited, the event get's duplicated duplicated into the new calendar (and a copy remains in the original calendar).

So:

- as an invitee I have no control over the calendar assigned to events to which I am invited on a Google Calendar (it will always be my default calendar) and
- as the organizer of an event, changing the calendar destroys or duplicates the event.

I must be missing something since my assumption has always been (and has always been the case for every other calendaring system I've used) that my "calendars" are simply private ways of categorizing my appointments, freely changeable by me, without any consequence for other attendees or invitees.

How do I change the calendar of an existing Google Calendar event?