# Google Calendar is showing canceled repeating meetings

Tags: google-calendar

My main calendar is on my mac in the macOS Calendar app.  I have shared the URL from that calendar, into Google so I can easily see my calendar on a Windows machine also (which I don't need often, just once in a while).

Years ago, I had a weekly meeting with a colleague.  He created the meeting and invited me, I was not the owner of the meeting.  We stopped these 3-4 years ago, and they were removed from my mac calendar.  But I just realized that those meetings are still appearing every Thursday evening.  They can't be deleted/canceled from Google, because I'm not the meeting owner.  This meetings does *not* exist on my mac calendar.  It is nowhere at all.   arch for it, and auto-fill does populate the search with the meeting title, but there are no instances of the meeting anywhere.

How can I get rid of this so that Google stops showing it?

Comment: See [Delete an event](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37113?hl=en). If you need further help, show what you have tried and add screenshots showing the details of the recurring event. Related [Change event's calendar when invited to event](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/40225/88163)

Comment: None of that applies.  On my mac calendar, this event does not exist.  There is nothing to delete.  And on Google Calendar, I can't delete it I presume because I'm not the owner.  I can't decline it either.  There is no option to do anything with it.  There is no Remove option, there are in fact no options at all.